# Special Equation Solving - 2

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a special complex equation as :

$$1+\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} \frac{m_i}{s+jp_i}=0$$

Any idea on finding the answers of it?

Comment: Good attempt at formatting! But you need to remember to enclose math between \$ symbols (or \$\$ for larger display, as above).

Comment: Is $j=\sqrt{-1}$? [math guys tend to use $i$ not $j$]. Are $m_i,p_i$ real? Are you trying to solve for (complex) $s$?

Comment: yes, the $j=\sqrt{-1}$ and $m_i$ and $p_i$ are real values. yes, we need to solve for complex s. Once we found the results, we later can go to more complicates assumptions.

Comment: To anyone interested, this explains what is the use of solving such an equation: https://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/PoleZero.pdf

Comment: You can try to just multiply out the fractions, this will give a polynomial equation for $s$ of degree $n-2$. Hence you will have that many complex solutions for $s$. I don't think you can do better for arbitrary real $m_i$ and $p_i$.

Comment: I think it has to do with finding the roots of a sum of Lagrange polynomials.

Comment: @Jeanba , yes, I think so but how can I do that?